# " app.candidates is not a function" getting these error while caling the function through truffle console with "app.candidate'

Tags: truffle, blockchain, console

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Election {
    //Model a Candidate
    struct Candidate {
        uint id;
        string name;
        uint voteCount;
    }

    //Store Candidate
    //Fetch Candidate
    mapping(uint => Candidate) public candidates;
    // Store Candidates Count
    uint public candidatesCount;

    function Elections () public {
        addCandidate("Candidate 1");
        addCandidate("Candidate 2");
    }

    function addCandidate (string memory _name) private {
        candidatesCount ++;
        candidates[candidatesCount] = Candidate(candidatesCount, _name, 0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

*You are using Solidity version 0.5.0*

If your contract name is "Elections", it must now be changed to include the constructor call explicitly. See the "breaking" changes in Solidity 0.5.0 [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/050-breaking-changes.html)!.

Change the constructor call from `function Elections () public` to `constructor () public`

For this program execution:

1. After the above changes, execute your contract once again on your local network using `truffle migrate --reset`
2. Now get back to your truffle console and use `Election.deployed().then(function (i) { app = i })` followed by
3. `app.candidates` or `app.candidates[0]`